# Sql to extract two columns into two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two crop few fields from a Oracle table and add them to a single table.

```
| Name       | brand       | Details      |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| Shirt      |        Ethos|   XXX  
| Mobile     |      Apple  |    XXX
| Laptop     |        Acer |    XXX 
| Mouse      |          HP |    XXX  
| Notepad    |       Archee|    XXX
| Coffee cup |     IKAI    |   XXX
```

From the above table I need the Name and the Brand into a new table as rows

Like below

```
Sno   |  Keywords
 1    |  Shirt
 2    |  Ethos
 3    |  Mobile
 4    |  Apple
 5    |  Laptop
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` and sequence to generate `Sno`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;

INSERT INTO new_table(Sno, Keywords)
SELECT my_seq.nextval, Name FROM old_table
UNION ALL
SELECT my_seq.nextval, Brand FROM old_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, If i dont need the sequence no then I can just do a union, Am I right?

Comment: @xtreme Yes, you can skip sequence, if you have values from `SNO` from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `sno` like this:

```
WITH ids ( rn, name, brand ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, Name, Brand
  FROM   Your_Table
)
SELECT 2*RN - 1 AS sno,
       Name AS Keywords
FROM   ids
UNION ALL
SELECT 2*RN,
       Brand
FROM   ids;
```